# How to configure 'build_common.xml' Ant file for Proguard and ORMLite in java application

Tags: java, xml, ant, proguard, ormlite

I have a Java application running on PC (Windows). 
I use Netbeans.

I use Proguard to obfuscate the code and I configure the obfuscation by the build_common.xml (Ant) file; therefore the ProGuard configuration options are given  by XML configuration tags.
I'm not expert at all of Xml, Proguard, I just copied and adapted some pieces of codes got in the web for my purposes and it worked.

Recently I introduced in my code ORMLite. When I run from IDE (so without obfuscation) my code works, but when I build with obfuscation it doesn't work.
Inside build_common.xml I excluded the "class com.j256.**" library, by:

```
<keep name="com.**" >    <method name="*" />    <field name="*" />   </keep>
```

but it isn't enought because probably ORMLite uses special annotations.

I found out some post, suggesting to use for example:

```
            -keepattributes *DatabaseField*
            -keepattributes *DatabaseTable*
            -keepattributes *SerializedName*
            -keep class com.j256.**
            -keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
            -keep enum com.j256.**
            -keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
            -keep interface com.j256.**
            -keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }            
            -dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.logger.**
            -dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.misc.**
```

but I don't know how to write those options in XML; I did some trying but it didn't work.

Can anybody help? Moreover on how to exclude from obfuscation ORMLite annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Founded out the solution:

simply added inside the proguard tags of 'build_common.xml' file the line:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

`the rest of the lines mensioned in my question seems unusefull